# Grouping Mongo DB document with three nested arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a Mongo document with three nested arrays. Inside the document `linearTvSessions`, I have an array of `linearTvChannels` which has an array of `sessions` which has an array of `tunerDetails`.

```
{
  "_id": "GATES:1123:E8186354149C:2022-03-04",
  "date": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1646352000000"
    }
  },
  "lastReportedTime": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1646436034000"
    }
  },
  "macAddress": "E8186354149C",
  "propCode": "GATES",
  "roomNumber": "1123",
  "linearTvChannels": [
    {
      "channelId": 3,
      "channelName": "WMC",
      "sessions": [
        {
          "created": {
            "$date": {
              "$numberLong": "1646435214000"
            }
          },
          "duration": 170,
          "isOccupied": 0,
          "startTime": {
            "$date": {
              "$numberLong": "1646435044000"
            }
          },
          "stopTime": {
            "$date": {
              "$numberLong": "1646435214000"
            }
          },
          "tunerDetails": [
            {
              "created": {
                "$date": {
                  "$numberLong": "1646435044000"
                }
              },
              "errorLevel": 0,
              "signalLevel": 44,
              "signalLocked": 1,
              "signalQuality": 91
            },
            {
              "created": {
                "$date": {
                  "$numberLong": "1646435104000"
                }
              },
              "errorLevel": 0,
              "signalLevel": 4487,
              "signalLocked": 0,
              "signalQuality": 1111
            },
            {
              "created": {
                "$date": {
                  "$numberLong": "1646435164000"
                }
              },
              "errorLevel": 0,
              "signalLevel": 44,
              "signalLocked": 0,
              "signalQuality": 63
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Current output:

```
{
    _id: 'GATES:1123:E8186354149C:2022-03-04',
    lastReportedTime: 2022 - 03 - 04 T23: 20: 34.000 Z,
    propCode: 'GATES',
    roomNumber: '1123',
    macAddress: 'E8186354149C',
    date: 2022 - 03 - 04 T00: 00: 00.000 Z,
    linearTvChannels: [{
        channelName: 'WMC',
        channelId: 3,
        sessions: [{
            created: 2022 - 03 - 04 T23: 06: 54.000 Z,
            duration: 170,
            isOccupied: 0,
            startTime: 2022 - 03 - 04 T23: 04: 04.000 Z,
            stopTime: 2022 - 03 - 04 T23: 06: 54.000 Z,
            tunerDetails: {
                created: 2022 - 03 - 04 T23: 05: 04.000 Z,
                errorLevel: 0,
                signalLevel: 4487,
                signalLocked: 0,
                signalQuality: 1111
            }
        },
        {
            created: 2022 - 03 - 04 T23: 06: 54.000 Z,
            duration: 170,
            isOccupied: 0,
            startTime: 2022 - 03 - 04 T23: 04: 04.000 Z,
            stopTime: 2022 - 03 - 04 T23: 06: 54.000 Z,
            tunerDetails: {
                created: 2022 - 03 - 04 T23: 06: 04.000 Z,
                errorLevel: 0,
                signalLevel: 44,
                signalLocked: 0,
                signalQuality: 63
            }
        }]
    }]
}
```

Desired output:

```
{
    _id: 'GATES:1123:E8186354149C:2022-03-04',
    lastReportedTime: 2022 - 03 - 04 T23: 20: 34.000 Z,
    propCode: 'GATES',
    roomNumber: '1123',
    macAddress: 'E8186354149C',
    date: 2022 - 03 - 04 T00: 00: 00.000 Z,
    linearTvChannels: [{
        channelName: 'WMC',
        channelId: 3,
        sessions: [{
            created: 2022 - 03 - 04 T23: 06: 54.000 Z,
            duration: 170,
            isOccupied: 0,
            startTime: 2022 - 03 - 04 T23: 04: 04.000 Z,
            stopTime: 2022 - 03 - 04 T23: 06: 54.000 Z,
            tunerDetails: [{
                created: 2022 - 03 - 04 T23: 05: 04.000 Z,
                errorLevel: 0,
                signalLevel: 4487,
                signalLocked: 0,
                signalQuality: 1111
            },
            {
                created: 2022 - 03 - 04 T23: 06: 04.000 Z,
                errorLevel: 0,
                signalLevel: 44,
                signalLocked: 0,
                signalQuality: 63
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

My Current query:

```
db.linearTvSessions.aggregate(
   [{$unwind:"$linearTvChannels"}, {$unwind:"$linearTvChannels.sessions"}, {$unwind:"$linearTvChannels.sessions.tunerDetails"},
   {$match:{"linearTvChannels.sessions.tunerDetails.signalLocked":0}},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "channelName": "$linearTvChannels.channelName",
            "channelId": "$linearTvChannels.channelId"
        },
        "lastReportedTime": { "$first": "$lastReportedTime" },
        "propCode": { "$first": "$propCode" },
        "roomNumber": { "$first": "$roomNumber" },
        "macAddress": { "$first": "$macAddress" },
        "date": { "$first": "$date" },
        "sessions": { "$push": "$linearTvChannels.sessions" }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id._id",
        "lastReportedTime": { "$first": "$lastReportedTime" },
        "propCode": { "$first": "$propCode" },
        "roomNumber": { "$first": "$roomNumber" },
        "macAddress": { "$first": "$macAddress" },
        "date": { "$first": "$date" },
        "linearTvChannels": { "$push": {
            "channelName": "$_id.channelName",
            "channelId": "$_id.channelId",
            "sessions": "$sessions"
        }}
    }}
   ]
);
```

I `unwind` the three arrays in the query above and inside the third array `tunerDetails`, I'm matching on the `signalLocked` field. I'm having trouble grouping the `tunerDetails` in an array by `sessions`. In my output above, each `tunerDetails` is placed in a redundant `session`. This is expected behavior but I'm trying to place the `tunerDetails` in an array as shown in my desired output.

I create a third `group` operation with the id of `sessions` details similar to this but I'm loosing track of `linearTvChannels` details when I do so.

```
{ "$group": {
      "_id": {
          "created": "$linearTvChannels.sessions.created",
          "duration": "$linearTvChannels.sessions.duration",
          "isOccupied": "$linearTvChannels.sessions.isOccupied",
          "startTime": "$linearTvChannels.sessions.startTime",
          "stopTime": "$linearTvChannels.sessions.stopTime"
      },
      "tunerDetails": { "$push": "$linearTvChannels.sessions.tunerDetails" }
    }}
```

I feel like I'm not grouping by the ids properly?

Comment: Is the overall goal here to remove all sessions entries with signalLocked: 1?

Comment: The goal is to only collect sessions entries with a tunerDetails entry that has the signalLocked field = 0. If there is a session and non of the tunerDetails entries have a signalLocked = 0, ignore that session. If the session entry has multiple tunerDetails entries, only collect the tunerDetails entries where signalLocked field = 0 and return that session.

Comment: If we take the two signalLocked fields that are zero and set them equal to 1, the result should be a linearTvChannel, channelId = 3, channelName = WMC with an empty sessions array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the innermost array is the only thing to be modified, you could accomplish this with `$map` and `$filter`:

- $map over `linearTvChannels`, replace with the result of the map
- $map over `sessions`, replace with the result of the map
- $filter `tunerDetails`, keeping only those with `signalLocked` 0

This could be done in a single `$addFields` stage like so:

```
{$addFields: {
    linearTvChannels: {$map: {
        input: "$linearTvChannels",
        as: "chan",
        in: {$mergeObjects: [
              "$$chan",
              {sessions: {
                $map: {
                  input: "$$chan.sessions",
                  as: "session",
                  in: {"$mergeObjects": [
                        "$$session",
                        {tunerDetails: {
                          $filter: {
                            input: "$$session.tunerDetails",
                            cond: {$eq: ["$$this.signalLocked",0]}
                          }
                        }}
                  ]}
                }
              }}
        ]}
      }
    }
}}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/F0jVpYbmUI3)